# How to ReUse Ubuntu APT

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, aptitude

When we use

> ubuntu apt-get

the first process is downloading the required files into a temporary folder

> /var/cache/apt/archives

Installation will be done only after that.
Can we able to migrate these files into a different system so that we can install those applications without using internet.

ie when typing following command

> apt-get application-name

the system should take the required files from this temporary folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many other tools in the Apt family that can assist with managing packages.

- `apt-move` can build a local "installed packages only" repository,
- `apt-cacher` or `apt-cacher-ng` are caching proxies,
- `apt-proxy` is another proxy and partial mirror builder,
- `apt-zip` can update a non-networked computer using Apt and removable media (Zip here refers to the old 100MB floppy-like media, not the compression),
- `aptoncd` creates CD-based repositories with packages downloaded by Apt

These are available as individual packages; for the most part, you'd install them on the machine with network access to the official Apt repositories, and use them to create package repositories on removable media (for `apt-zip` or `aptoncd`) or configure that machine to be a local repository that other machines on the local network can access (for the various proxies and `apt-move`).

As Broam points out in the comments, if you have differing architectures some of these will be more useful than others.

Comment: and this is not to say you can't just reuse packages from `/var/cache/apt/archives` directly via `dpkg`.  for one-off updates that's perfectly viable.  but these are tools designed to automate the process and enable you to keep a network of Ubuntu machines updated.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do that. `apt-get` will look at cache folder first, and if the version of the package you wanna install is the same with the cache version, `apt-get` will use the cache version without going to internet

Comment: If the systems are the same architecture (or the package is arch all).

There's no point caching i386 packages for use on an amd64 system, etc.

Answer (score 3):

two options i can think of - use dpkg to install the packages or use [aptoncd](http://aptoncd.sourceforge.net/)